# WSO2DSS service converting null value to ' '(one single space)

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server

I am trying to call a db function via DSS service. That db function is basically written for updating user values in database which it got from dss as input.

In my db function,if it gets null value as input it wont update the user detail in my postgres database else it will update. I achieved this using the COALESCE function. I tested this functionality of db function seaparately and it is working fine.

But when i pass null value to the function via dss, dss converts null to ''(single space) and pass it to the function. Function on not receiving null updates Database field with one single space.

Now for because of this issue, i had to write some more logic inside my COALESCE function.

**i want to know that why dss converting null value to ' '?**

My db function is as follows

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION modify_user(customer_id_in character varying, email_id_in character varying, mobile_in character varying, first_name_in character varying, last_name_in character varying)
  RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
     IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ildb_schema.customer_detail WHERE identifier = customer_id_in) THEN 
 UPDATE ildb_schema.customer_detail 
 SET first_name=COALESCE(first_name_in,first_name),
     last_name=COALESCE(last_name_in,last_name),
     mobile_number=COALESCE(mobile_in,mobile_number),
     email=COALESCE(email_id_in,email),
     last_modify=now() 
     WHERE identifier = customer_id_in 
     AND (first_name_in IS NOT NULL AND first_name_in IS DISTINCT FROM first_name 
   OR last_name_in IS NOT NULL AND last_name_in IS DISTINCT FROM last_name 
   OR mobile_in IS NOT NULL AND mobile_in IS DISTINCT FROM mobile_number 
   OR email_id_in IS NOT NULL AND email_id_in IS DISTINCT FROM email);
     RETURN 1;
     END IF;
     RETURN 0;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION ildb_schema.modify_user(character varying, character varying, character varying, character varying, character varying)
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

DSS is as follows.

```
<data name="update_test">
   <config id="ildb">
      <property name="carbon_datasource_name">test_database</property>
   </config>
    <query id="update_function" useConfig="ildb">
      <sql>select * from modify_user(:cid,:email,:mob,:fn,:ln)</sql>
      <result element="customer" rowName="">
         <element column="modify_user" name="modify_user" xsdType="string"/>
      </result>
      <param defaultValue="null" name="cid" sqlType="STRING"/>
      <param defaultValue="null" name="email" sqlType="STRING"/>
      <param defaultValue="null" name="mob" sqlType="STRING"/>
      <param defaultValue="null" name="fn" sqlType="STRING"/>
      <param defaultValue="null" name="ln" sqlType="STRING"/>
   </query>
      <operation name="update_function_op1">
      <call-query href="update_function">
         <with-param name="cid" query-param="cid"/>
         <with-param name="email" query-param="email"/>
         <with-param name="mob" query-param="mob"/>
         <with-param name="fn" query-param="fn"/>
         <with-param name="ln" query-param="ln"/>
      </call-query>
   </operation>
     <resource method="PUT" path="/update/function">
      <call-query href="update_function">
         <with-param name="cid" query-param="cid"/>
         <with-param name="email" query-param="email"/>
         <with-param name="mob" query-param="mob"/>
         <with-param name="fn" query-param="fn"/>
         <with-param name="ln" query-param="ln"/>
      </call-query>
   </resource>
</data>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to set the default value to null, set it as "#{NULL}". For an example,

```
<param defaultValue="#{NULL}" name="name" sqlType="STRING"/>
```

For more info please refer [this doc](https://docs.wso2.com/display/DSS322/Adding+Input+Mappings#AddingInputMappings-Defaultvalue).